# Xcode button (IBAction) only working once

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm new to iOS development. I'm trying to make a very simple application that rotates an image on a button press. The code works fine, but only once - i.e. the image rotates one time and then the button can no longer be pressed.

I've searched and found many similar issues, but nothing seems to fix my problem. Below is my ViewController.swift code.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var rotateImage: UIButton!
    @IBAction func rotateImage(_ sender: Any) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, animations: {
            self.imageName.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: (90.0 * .pi) / 90.0)
        })
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var imageName: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
}
```

Ideally, the code should allow for multiple button presses, enabling the user to rotate the image as much as they would like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gets called multiple times, but it does the same rotation each time so nothing visually changes.

You can look into using a variable for your `rotationAngle` based on the image orientation so that it keeps rotating in your desired direction with each click.

An easy example takes your code and then uses a random value for the angle.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageName: UIImageView!

    @IBAction func rotateImage(_ sender: Any) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, animations: {
            self.imageName.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: (CGFloat.random(in: 0 ..< 360) * .pi) / 90.0)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem @RandyOram, you can look up capturing the image orientation of a UIImage if you want to change it such that it uses that value.